# извлечение переменной из redux store

Tags: redux, react-native

Добрый день, необходимо извлечь props из store в компоненте ***calculate*** и передать результаты вычисления с ним в ***app***

> app.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import principalChanged from './src/actions';
    import  Input from './src/components/common';
    import  { principal2, principal3 } from './src/components/calculate';

      class App extends Component {
        onPrincipalChange(text) {           
          this.props.principalChanged(text); 
        }
      render() {
        return ( 
            <Card>
               <Input 
                 placeholder="Placeholder" 
                 label="Label" 
                 onChangeText={this.onPrincipalChange.bind(this)} 
                 value={this.props.principal}                      
                />
              `Текущее состояние переменной: ${this.props.principal}`{/n}
              `Новая переменная: ${principal2}`
              `Новая переменная: ${principal3}`
            </Card>
        );
       }
       }
const mapStateToProps = state => { 
   return { 
      principal: state.form.principal
   }; 
}; 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { 
    principalChanged 
})(App);
```

> calculate.js

```
// вызов переменной principal из store
// каким то образом
export const principal2 = (principal) => {     
     return ( { principal * 2 } ); // вычисления 
}; 

export const principal3 = (principal) => {     
     return ( { principal / 2 } ); // вычисления
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не возможно подключить Redux (react-redux) к функции. Необходимо всегда подключать его к компоненту через ***connect***. Как это сделано в компоненте App.js.

То, что я искал, называется селектором или селекторной логикой. Просто необходимо вызвать функции (calculate.js) в подключении (connect) и, таким образом, внедрить  нужные вычисленные значения  (props) в компонент. Не нужно использовать mergeProps.

[Решение здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281982/extracting-a-variable-from-the-redux-store/47282479#47282479)

Альтернативный вариант (описан в комментариях по ссылке выше):

> app.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import principalChanged from './src/actions';
    import  Input from './src/components/common';
    import { calculate } from './src/lib';

      class App extends Component {
        onPrincipalChange(text) {           
          this.props.principalChanged(text); 
        }
      render() {
      const { principal2, principal3 } = calculate(this.props.principal);
        return ( 
            <Card>
               <Input 
                 placeholder="Placeholder" 
                 label="Label" 
                 onChangeText={this.onPrincipalChange.bind(this)} 
                 value={this.props.principal}                      
                />
               Текущее состояние переменной: ${this.props.principal}{/n}
               Новая переменная: ${principal2}
               Новая переменная: ${principal3}
            </Card>
        );
       }
       }
const mapStateToProps = state => { 
   return { 
      principal: state.form.principal
   }; 
}; 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { 
    principalChanged 
})(App);
```

> ```
> calculate.js
> ```

```
export const calculate = (principal) => {
   const result = {};
   result.principal2 = principal * 2;
   result.principal3 = result.principal2 / 4;   
   return result;
};
```